# Convert raw word document to readable document in Flutter

Tags: flutter, byte, docx, raw

I'm building a Flutter app and need to read files from an API. But the API delivers raw data like:

Postman screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzqUA.png

Does anyone know how to parse this raw data in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

That data looks like a Word docx file, which is technically a ZIP archive. You could use [flutter_archive](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_archive) to extract the individual data files. You still need to parse the resulting XML to get something "readable".